# Where is Safari Reader CSS or HTML in El Capitan?

Tags: macos, html, css, safari

In OS X El Capitan, Safari Reader View file for modifying the CSS is no longer found in Safari application and in `/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Safari.framework/Versions/A/Resources/`.

Where is it located?

Is it locked by System Integration too?

If there is no way to modify, I think in downgrading to OS X Yosemite.

Comment: If the file is protected by SIP, then you can disable, edit the file, and re-enable SIP.

Comment: Isn't the file `Reader.html` inside that folder?

Comment: I have already searched all the folders and I didn't find.

Answer (score 1):

I tried `mdfind -name Reader.html` and on my copy of El Capitan it yields the following path:

`/System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/SafariShared.framework/Versions/A/Resources/Reader.html`

So it looks like the file has indeed been moved.